# Is it good from SEO perspective to use Content in Side Stickers?

Tags: seo, content

Please advise is it good from SEO perspective if my website content is in side sticker like in attached Screen Shot. If I will click any where outside this content get hide, also I need to use slider to read the whole content.

[image: Attached ScreenShot]

Comment: Impossible to tell. It depends on the code and how yo do this.

Comment: Thank you for including the screen shot with this question.  Without it, I wouldn't have know what a "side sticker" was.

Comment: Sorry, If I am wrongly pronouncing it. What would you call it?

Answer (score 1):

Content that is visible to the user when the page loads will be readily indexed by Google.   The fact that the user can hide the content shouldn't make Google like it any less.

Conversely, if the sticker were hidden by default and the user had to click something to show it, the content in it would be much less likely to be indexed by Google.

Neither case is against the Google webmaster guidelines.   Google won't put a penalty in place as long as content can be opened and read by users easily.

Google generally indexes text that requires scrolling to get to when the top portion of the text is visible.   Scroll bars are usually for the whole page, but I haven't seen indexing problems when using scrolling on smaller page portions.

It would be against the webmaster guidelines to put content into a hidden section that can never be read by users.  Google does prohibit that  in their webmaster guidelines:  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en.